# Scannerless arithmetic parser does not find syntax error i'am not sure why?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have been working on this simple scannerless recursive parser but when i feed it an arithmetic expression it runs throw it without printing syntax error message even if the input is grammatically incorrect.

```
    <expr>   ::= <term> "+" <expr>   | 
                 <term> "-" <expr>   | 
                 <term>

    <term>   ::= <factor> "*" <term> | 
                 <factor> "/" <term> | 
                 <factor>

    <factor> ::= <number> <factor>   | 
                 "(" <expr> ")"      | 
                 "-" <factor>       
    
    <number> ::= <digit> <number>    |
                 <digit> 

    <digit> ::= "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | 
                "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | 
                "8" | "9"
```

```
let input = '**5', 
    index = 0, 
    char = input[index];

function match(c) { 
    if(char === c) {
        index++;
        char = input[index];

        if(index >= input.length) {
            char = '$';
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception('Syntax error.');
    }
}

function digit() {
    if(char === '0') match('0');
    else if(char === '1') match('1');
    else if(char === '2') match('2');
    else if(char === '3') match('3');
    else if(char === '4') match('4');
    else if(char === '5') match('5');
    else if(char === '6') match('6');
    else if(char === '7') match('7');
    else if(char === '8') match('8');
    else if(char === '9') match('9');
}

function number() {
    digit();
    if('0123456789'.includes(char)) {
        number();
    }
}

function factor() {
    if('0123456789'.includes(char)) {
        number();
        factor();
    }
    else if(char === '(') {
        match('(');
        expression();
        match(')');
    }
    else if(char === '-') {
        match('-');
        factor();
    }
}

function term() {
    factor();
    if(char === '*') {
        match('*');
        term();
    }
    else if(char === '/') {
        match('/');
        term();
    }
}

function expression() {
    term();
    if(char === '+') {  
        match('+');
        expression();
    }
    else if(char === '-') {
        match('-');
        expression();
    }
}

expression();
```

It' seems that recursive functions does not enter match function at the right time where the incorrect input exist, but i dont know if my grammar is the problem or my BNF to code translation?

Comment: Your BNF is fine. You are just not checking the syntax errors correctly. `match` is where the syntax error should be thrown, but you're only checking if the current character is equal to the expected character. So you'll only throw an error for that specific case fails.

Comment: so what would you suggest as replacement?